# 401.2 Unauthorized error when trying to access SharedServices for calling PSI extensions using impersonation

Tags: impersonation

I am working on a VS2010 machine to develop web parts for a MOSS 2007 server that has MS Project Server installed on it. I am trying to get a sample Impersonation application running on it. I am following this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974413%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

However, when I try to connect to SSP, it throws an error as 401.2 Unauthorized. I am working on a VPC with Admin login and Admin right to Sharepoint, MS Project Server. Please let me know what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either You need to add the yourself (or username you logged in with) to the SSP which hosts Project Web Access, or the SSP is not configured to process the user's account.

Try either or both step 1 or 2.

**Step 1**

Add the user to the SSP site with contribute access.

**Step 2**

To enable the SSP to process accounts, run the following *stsadm* Command.

```
stsadm -o editssp -title [SSPName] -setaccounts [accounts to add]
```

Comment: will try and let you know!

Comment: Amit, any link/process to do step 1?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428835.aspx#pj12_ImpersonationWeb_AccountSecurity

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2007 and MOSS 2007 are built on ASP.Net 2.0. The default ASP.NET version of VS2010 is 4. So maybe there's the problem.

If the problem is in your code, try to add a this (if you use c#)

```
try
{
  //Your code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Log error
}
```

Comment: I checked this and this is not a problem..

Comment: Did you try both? Or only the try catch?

Comment: I tried both..I also tried it with VS2005 but no luck..